# Overriding private methods?

Tags: java

I am extending `example.java`, and in this class there is a private method, `exampleMethod()`. Now, I want to have the same method in my class `secondexample.java` and call `super.exampleMethod()`. Since `exampleMethod()` in `example.java` is private I can't! How would I go about doing this?

Comment: It's likely private for a good reason.  You won't be able to override it but you could call it using reflection.

Comment: You can find the answer here.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398157/how-to-invoke-parent-private-method-from-child][1]

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a `private` function from a subclass. One thing you can do is change it to a `protected` method.
You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private) post for more about modifiers.

Comment: I should have been more clear in the post. I know about modifiers, but the class I am extending is from an API, so I can't edit its' contents.

Comment: If the `API` made the function `private` then they do not want others to change or call it. Modifiers are there for access control. However if you really need to call that method then you can change the modifier, even without having the source. Javas `Reflection` API allows you to change classes and everything at runtime. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880365/any-way-to-invoke-a-private-method